# Try to create reusable mat-table component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to build a mat-table reusable component, and my attempt is to allow show hide column from another component with a boolean **`@Input() semaphore: boolean;`** decorator.

#### table.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { TableLayout } from 'src/app/models/table-layout.model';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnChanges {
  console = console;
  @Input() records: any[];
  @Input() caption: string;
  @Input() settings: TableLayout[];
  @Input() select: boolean;
  @Input() semaphore: boolean;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  setColumns: TableLayout[];
  displayColumns: string[];

  keys: string[];
  dataSource: any;
  selection = new SelectionModel<TableLayout>(true, []);

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.tableSettings();
  }

  tableSettings() {
    if (this.settings) {
      this.setColumns = this.settings;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<TableLayout>(this.records);

      this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
        if (property.toLowerCase().includes(' ')) {
          return property.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_');
        }
        return item[property.toLowerCase()];
      };

      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

    } else {
      this.setColumns = Object.keys(this.records[0])
        .map(key => {
          return {
            primaryKey: key,
            header: key.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
              key.replace(/_/g, ' ').slice(1),
            format: 'default'
          };
        });
      }

    this.displayColumns = this.setColumns.map(column => column.header);
    this.displayColumns.splice(0, 0, 'Select');
    this.displayColumns.push('Semaphore');
  }

  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
        this.selection.clear() :
        this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }

  checkboxLabel(row?: TableLayout): string {
    if (!row) {
      return `${this.isAllSelected() ? 'select' : 'deselect'} all`;
    }
    return `${this.selection.isSelected(row) ? 'deselect' : 'select'} row ${row.header + 1}`;
  }
}
```

#### table.component.html

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let col of setColumns" [matColumnDef]="col.header">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ col.header }} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let record"> {{ record[col.primaryKey] | valueNotfound:col.format }} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Semaphore">
    <div *ngIf="semaphore">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="text-center">Magazzino</th>
    </div>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let record">
        <span  class="availability " [ngClass]="{
          'no-availability' : record['quantità'] < 10,
          'low-availability' : (record['quantità'] >= 10 && record['quantità'] <= 20),
          'high-availability' : record['quantità'] > 20
        }"></span>
      </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let record; columns: displayColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

#### reusable.component.html

```
<app-table [records]="itemInStore" [settings]="itemInStoreSettings" [select]="true" [semaphore]="true"></app-table>
```

but in some way the **`@Input() semaphore: boolean;`** decorator not work, it show always semaphore column

[image]

My goal instead is to allow developers to hide show column based on their boolean option like so:

#### reusable1.component.html

```
<app-table [records]="itemInStore" [settings]="itemInStoreSettings" [select]="true" [semaphore]="true"></app-table>
```

#### reusable2.component.html

```
<app-table [records]="itemInStore" [settings]="itemInStoreSettings" [select]="true" [semaphore]="false"></app-table>
```

I have a very simplyfied [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hideshow) about this function and this is not parallel to the above components, but has my attempts to reach this goal.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? I am asking because "Some one can help me please" is not really a question. I like the answer of [markratledge] though.

Comment: My question is: how can solve the spam injection and how can solve the visibiliy on google....

Answer (score 5):

There are too many hacking vectors to try and cover between WordPress, plugins, your users and your host; your question is far too broad.

You can start by carefully following [FAQ My site was hacked - WordPress Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked)

Then take a look at the recommended security measures in [Hardening WordPress - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and [Brute Force Attacks - WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks)

Scan your own PC. Tell your web host you got hacked; and consider changing to a more secure host: [Recommended WordPress Web Hosting.](http://wordpress.org/hosting/)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: how can solve the spam injection and how can solve the visibiliy on google....

**Spam injection** - Can be prevented by fixing all vulnerabilities, removing all back doors and changing all passwords (in that order).

**Visibility on Google** - After fixing the spam injection problem you need to request a review from Google. This can be done here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/docs/request_review